# Create horizontal list view with titanium alloy

Tags: listview, horizontal-scrolling, titanium-alloy

How to create horizontal list view with titanium alloy.
I have used layout = "horizontal" but it doesn't work

```
<ListView id="dynamicListView"  defaultItemTemplate ="image_title">

    <Templates>
        <ItemTemplate name="image_title" height="100">      
              <ImageView bindId="image" id="image"/>                    
        </ItemTemplate>
    </Templates>

    <ListSection layout = "horizontal">
    <ListSection/>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but you can't create horizontal listView, as it's been designed to present content horizontally:

> A list view is used to present information, organized in to sections and items, in a vertically-scrolling view.

You can use *TableView* or *ScrollView*, they both support horizontal scrolling ;)
Cheers